# Google Sheets: Comparing Columns with Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a to do list spreadsheet. In one column, `"Daily Tasks"`, I have a list of tasks. In the other column, I have checkboxes. My goal is to create a script that will add all of the "checked" tasks to an array.

I am attempting to do this in my script using a nested for loop. However, when I log my new array that should contain the checked items (trueArr), I see just a series of what appear to be empty arrays.

How do I change my script so that my array contains the checked items from my spreadsheet?

[Here is a link to my spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13upysp3_GD5sGwwdegHpJQuZC4gE2pVIGgf-ngu39sM/edit#gid=0)

Here is my code:

```js
//spreadsheet 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

//worksheet 
var todoList = ss.getSheetByName("To-Do List");


function completedArray(){
var tasks = todoList.getRange("c6:d22").getValues();
var checks = todoList.getRange("b6:b22").getValues();

var trueArr = [];
  
for(var i =0; i <tasks.length; i++){
  for(var j=0; j<checks.length;j++){
    if(checks[j]===true){
      trueArr.push(tasks[j]) 
            }  
        }
    Logger.log(trueArr);
    }
}
```

In my log, I expect to see the same items that are on my "Daily Tasks" list on my spreadsheet, but instead I only see empty arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation / Issues:

You are very close besides the following two things:

- The `checks` array is a 2 dimensional array since you use [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) to create it. Meaning that `checks[j]` is a **row** or in other words a 1 dimensional array. It is fundamentally wrong to compare an array with a value. Instead you should be using `checks[j][0]` in the `if` statement since this will iterate over each value of the single column. Another approach would be to use [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to convert the 2D array to 1D and then use your current code.
- The second issue has to do with a `for` loop that you don't use anywhere. Your code iterates over `i` but you don't use or need `i` in your code. Keep also in mind that `tasks` and `checks` have the same number of rows (same length), therefore one `for` loop is enough in this scenario.

### Solution:

```
//spreadsheet 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

//worksheet 
var todoList = ss.getSheetByName("To-Do List");


function completedArray(){
var tasks = todoList.getRange("c6:d22").getValues();
var checks = todoList.getRange("b6:b22").getValues();

var trueArr = [];
  

  for(var j=0; j<checks.length;j++){
    if(checks[j][0]===true){
      trueArr.push(tasks[j]) 
            } 
    }
  Logger.log(trueArr);
}
```

The structure of `trueArr` would be: `[[task2, task2], [task3, task3], [task9, task9]]` since `tasks[j]` is also a row or 1D array. This is why you will end up with a collection of 1D arrays.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your edit/explanation is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to create the same array of checked items using the filter method and an arrow function. Made a two dimensional array that includes both checkboxes and list items. Then I filtered by the checkboxes in the first column. No need for loops!

```js
//spreadsheet 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

//worksheet 
var todoList = ss.getSheetByName("To-Do List");
var dailies = todoList.getRange("b6:e22").getValues();



function checkedItems(){

var checkedItems = dailies.filter(row => row[0] === true); 

Logger.log(checkedItems);

}
```

Got the same result with a fraction of the code!